# Kubelet fails to update node status

Tags: kubernetes

On latest RHEL Atomic Host (Kubernetes 1.2) we are regularly seeing the following entries in the kubelet logs:

kubelet.go:2761] Error updating node status, will retry: nodes "x.y.z" cannot be updated: the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again

This causes the node to temporary go to NotReady. During these NotReady periods, the PODs on the node show Ready, but it looks like Kubernetes stops routing traffic to them, causing us a problem.

In the Go sources I can see that during the heartbeat of a Kubelet it does a GET to fetch the latest status, overwrites it with its own status, and sends the PUT back to the apiserver.

This is what we see in the logs:

`Jul 15 12:42:45 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:42:45.086322    3736 round_trippers.go:264] GET https://lxa160g.srv.pl.ing.net:6443/api/v1/nodes/lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net
Jul 15 12:42:45 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:42:45.091579    3736 round_trippers.go:289] Response Status: 200 OK in 5 milliseconds
Jul 15 12:42:45 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:42:45.373091    3736 round_trippers.go:264] PUT https://lxa160g.srv.pl.ing.net:6443/api/v1/nodes/lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net/status
Jul 15 12:42:45 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:42:45.409752    3736 round_trippers.go:289] Response Status: 200 OK in 36 milliseconds
Jul 15 12:42:55 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:42:55.411267    3736 round_trippers.go:264] GET https://lxa160g.srv.pl.ing.net:6443/api/v1/nodes/lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net
Jul 15 12:42:55 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:42:55.431056    3736 round_trippers.go:289] Response Status: 200 OK in 19 milliseconds
Jul 15 12:43:38 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:43:38.020203    3736 round_trippers.go:264] PUT https://lxa160g.srv.pl.ing.net:6443/api/v1/nodes/lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net/status
Jul 15 12:43:38 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:43:38.029575    3736 round_trippers.go:289] Response Status: 409 Conflict in 9 milliseconds
Jul 15 12:43:38 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:43:38.029772    3736 round_trippers.go:264] GET https://lxa160g.srv.pl.ing.net:6443/api/v1/nodes/lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net
Jul 15 12:43:38 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:43:38.034980    3736 round_trippers.go:289] Response Status: 200 OK in 5 milliseconds
Jul 15 12:43:38 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:43:38.298752    3736 round_trippers.go:264] PUT https://lxa160g.srv.pl.ing.net:6443/api/v1/nodes/lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net/status
Jul 15 12:43:38 lxa160j.srv.pl.ing.net kubelet[3736]: I0715 12:43:38.320192    3736 round_trippers.go:289] Response Status: 200 OK in 21 milliseconds`

So it takes a long time to fire a PUT after a successful GET. Why?

Thanks

Comment: By any chance do you have to nodes that both think they have the same node name, and they are fighting to update the same node object?

Comment: Hi Eric, we have six nodes that all show different names with `kubectl get no`. Note that this problem happens a couple of times a day. What can cause the kubelet to get out of sync with etcd's representation of the node?